# Laravel "whereHas" with "take"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm having a relationship:

**employees**: id | name

**employments**: id | employee_id | company_id | start_date | end_date | termination_type_id

One employee can have many employments through time. I need to get employees who are employed based on the **last/one** row in employments and that is whereHas fails me. I've set this in my model Employee.php:

In Employee.php model:

```
public function latestEmployment() {
  return $this->hasMany(Employment::class)->orderBy('start_date', 'DESC')->take(1);
}
```

On filtering:

```
$employees->where(function ($query) {
  $query->whereHas('latestEmployment', function($subquery) {
    $subquery->whereNull('termination_type_id');
  }
});
```

Looks to me that I need somewhere some eager loading because `->take(1)` doesn't work that way. Here whereHas takes into account the whole table, no matter what I write next.

Thanks for help.

EDIT:

Doing `first()`, `get()`, etc. executes the query in the middle so I cannot use that. Important thing is that the whole query needs to be a Builder because I need a `paginate()` at the end.

Comment: use `->first()` instead of `->take(1)`

Comment: @NullCod3 `take()` and `limit()` functions will not work with eager loading if you retrieve parent model more than one.

Comment: @HH - I don't think I can just use ->first(). It's not within "hasMany" and I cannot use it within Builder and later in whereHas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is getting all employees and filtering them afterwards:

```php
public function latestEmployment() {
    return $this->hasOne(Employment::class)->orderBy('start_date', 'DESC');
}

Employee::with('latestEmployment')->get()
    ->where('latestEmployment.termination_type_id', null);
```

A query that only fetches the relevant employees:

```php
Employee::select('employees.*')
    ->join('employments', 'employees.id', 'employments.employee_id')
    ->whereNull('termination_type_id')
    ->where('start_date', function($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('max(start_date)')
            ->from('employments')
            ->whereColumn('employee_id', 'employees.id');
    })->get();
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the solution I didn't want to make, first doing a get() and then filter. Especially because I have a paginate() at the end.

Comment: It can also be done within a query but that is more complicated. Would you like a query solution?

Comment: If you know how to do it without doing get(), first(), and paginate() in the middle of a query, yes! I'm trying it for days! Important thing is that I can do paginate() on the Builder at the end. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this

```
Employee::select('employees.*')->join('employments', function ($join) {
            $join->on('employees.id', '=', 'employments.employee_id')
                 ->whereNull('emails.termination_type_id');
        })->distinct()->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not taking only last row in the $join clause.